# TinyMCE (with Ajax) - Re-adding editor causes undefined error

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

I am reloading content of a div using an ajax request.

```
  <div>
        <textarea id="content-value" rows="15" cols="40" class="tinymce" style="width:100%"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Within this div I have a text area that is initialized with tinymce...

```
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector: "tinymce",
            theme : "advanced",
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|formatselect,fontsizeselect,|,code",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
            height: "340",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false
        });
```

After loading the content with an AJAX request, I remove the editor, replace the content, and then attempt to re-add the editor to tinyMCE.

```
   function OnCreateResponse(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, 'content-value');
                $(dlgElem).html(response.html);
                tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'content-value');
            }
        }
    }
```

Upon re-adding tinyMCE gives me the following error

> Error: tinyMCE.get("content-value") is
>   undefined

when executing ...

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, 'content-value');
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am also using this in a JQuery dialog, which causes the initialization to happen on open, and the tinymce editor to be removed onclose.  I imagine this is the difference, however good to know that its working when used normally.